# Using Dropify file input in an Angular 4 component

Tags: jquery, angular, dropify

I want to use the [Dropify](https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify) component in my Angular 4 project. However, all I get after applying the `.dropify` class to my `input` is the default file input with the "Choose file" button and filename label. How do I get the Dropify drag 'n drop file input to show?

As per Dropify's requirements, I've included JQuery and Dropify's script, stylesheet, and font in their respective locations:

- `jquery.min.js` included in `.angular-cli.json`'s `apps.scripts` array
- `dropify.min.js` included in `.angular-cli.json`'s `apps.scripts` array
- `dropify.css` included in `.angular-cli.json`'s `apps.styles` array
- Roboto font (needed for Dropify) `@import`ed in `src/styles.css`

`src/app/app.component.html`:

```
...
<div style="padding-bottom: 1.25em;">
  <input type="file" id="input" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="csv" formControlName="studentList" required>
</div>
...
```

`src/app/app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    const dragAndDrop = $('.dropify').dropify({
      messages: {
        'default': 'Drag and drop a CSV file here or click'
      }
    });
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

`src/styles.css`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "~http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900|Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700";
```

`.angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "apps": {
    ...
    "styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/dropify/dist/css/dropify.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/dropify/dist/js/dropify.min.js"
    ],
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: and no need to add the fonts separately. css file will find the fonts(if there) automatically. 
and why const dragAndDrop. just bind it on ngOnInit.

Comment: No error from Chrome console.

Comment: let dropify load after everyhing loads, like setting a timeout.

Comment: Hi. I'm getting an error here. It says that $('').dropify is not a function.

Answer (score 4):

Without any error, it's impossible to give you any solution. But I am giving here a sample use case. It might help you.

1. `npm install dropify --save`
2. Add the .js and .css file to .angular-cli.json or index file.
3. HTML input element `<input type="file" (change)="imageChanged($event)" class="dropify" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" data-allowed-file-extensions="jpg png jpeg" data-max-file-size="300K">`
4. in .ts file `declare var $: any;`
5. `ngOnInit() { $('.dropify').dropify({}); }`

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with JQuery in Angular 4, solved it by adding another declaration in the app.component.ts:

`declare var jquery:any;`
Hope it works!

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dropify still fails to load after adding the `jquery` declaration.